# Write object to XML file (specify my own file name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, file

So there's the basic function like this ....

def show
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @position }
end
```

end

and if you go to, say, http://localhost/(position_id).xml then you will see the xml...  But I wish to have a standard xml filename that I can write the object details to because I want to access it from outside rails.  I am very new to rails and have not programmed in a while...seems like this should be easy, right ?  So I just want to have a file created with a name like my_xml.xml for all the objects, rather than 1.xml, 2.xml, (id).xml, etc.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I met similar questions, here is my solution(I am a newbie):

I added below in **routes.rb**:

```
resources do
  collection do
    get 'my_xml'
  end
end
```

Then added the **my_xml** action in controller. In my_xml action, assemble all data, and format it to xml via **to_xml** method.

No sure whether above is useful for you. Hope it helpful.